# QtMultimedia Video Play example

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, gstreamer, qtmultimedia

I have Qt5 built with submodule QtMultimedia on Debian Jessie 8.2 (BeagleBone Black), I use GStreamer backend (version 0.10.36). I tried to use [this simple example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGKmQy-VBX0&list=LLAP24UQEHrQffkKRe2jaQag) to play a video, but it gives me error when trying to play .AVI file: Internal data flow error.

Is the problem in video plugins/codecs I have?

Here is the code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QVideoWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
    QVideoWidget *vw = new QVideoWidget;

    player->setVideoOutput(vw);

    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/debian/video.avi"));

    vw->setGeometry(100, 100, 320, 240);
    vw->show();

    player->play();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Kindly add the code, you have tried, here so that everyone can view it and can answer your query

Comment: @JafferWilson I posted code.

Comment: Try to run gst-launch playbin2 uri=file
to make sure that it works without qt.